# Finding $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^\alpha \sum\limits_{k \geq n+1} a_k$ when the series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\alpha > 0$ is given and the sequence $\{a_k\}$ consists of positive terms and we know that the series $\sum\limits_{k = n+1} a_k$ converges

Can we say anything about the limit of the product?

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^\alpha \sum\limits_{k = n+1}^\infty a_k$

I assume that it will depend in how quickly the tail of the series approaches zero. I am starting by assuming that $a_k = k^{-p}$ to make this easier, I am hoping that depending on the exponents we get some series where the limit exists and some where it is infinite, but I am not sure how to go and try to prove this.

Comment: Consider a monotonically decreasing function $f(x)$ on $[1,+\infty)$ for which $f(k)=a_k$. Then the problem is essentially equivalent to studying $x^a\int_x^\infty f(t)\mathrm dt$ given that $\int_1^\infty f(t)\mathrm dt$ converges.

Comment: Let $b_n$ strictly decreasing, with limit $0$ and put $a_n=b_n-b_{n+1}>0$. Then the series $a_n$ is positive, convergent and $b_{n+1}=\sum_{k\geq n+1}a_k$. As we have no other condition on $b_n$,  you cannot say something for your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an arbitrary increasing sequence of positive numbers $c_n>0$, put
$a_1=c_1$ and for $n>1$, $a_n=c_{n}-c_{n-1}$. Then for every $N$
$$\sum_{n=1}^Na_n=c_1+(c_2-c_1)+\cdots (c_N-c_{N-1})=c_N$$
in particular, the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ converges to a finite limit if and only if the sequence converges to the same finite limit. Thus, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=c_0$, say, then
$$\sum_{k>n}a_k=c_0-\sum_{k=1}^na_n=c_0-c_n$$
So that
$$n^{\alpha}\sum_{k>n}a_k=n^{\alpha}(c_0-c_n)$$
Since the sequence $c_0-c_n$ is an *arbitrary sequence that decreases to zero*, we can choose $c_n$ so that the product $n^{\alpha}(c_0-c_n)$ will behave as anyway as we prescribe, when $n\to\infty$, so we cannot say anything about it.

P.S -- Just noticed that as I was writing this Kelenner already had made a comment which is essentially the same argument.